# Columns and footnotes in XSL-FO

Tags: xsl-fo, apache-fop

I am trying to style an article, which has to be two-clumned. Is there any way how to get footnotes work properly in a such scenario? I am using FOP 1.1.

Styles:

[Page masters.](http://46.28.111.241:8081/exist/rest/db/apps/karolinum-apps/resources/xsl-fo/auc/geographica/page-masters-print-auc-geographica.xsl)

[Params.](http://46.28.111.241:8081/exist/rest/db/apps/karolinum-apps/resources/xsl-fo/auc/geographica/params-fo-print-auc-geographica.xsl)

The problem:

[image]

As [this official example](https://www.w3.org/Style/XSL/TestSuite/contrib/FOP/columns.pdf) shows on page 2, it could be the limit of the FOP.

**UPDATE**

(I guess it is this [bug](https://bz.apache.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=51304).).

Comment: You ask: Hope this could be somehow solved (Could it be this bug?). Apache FOP is open source, download the code and contribute. That is how it can be solved.

Comment: Thanks, however, I am not a Java developer. I was just desperate because of the suspicion.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In FOP, there really is the [bug](https://bz.apache.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=51304) I mentioned before. Because of that, the problem is not solvable at the moment.